# Query to pull every 10 data from the table in SQLLite

Tags: android, mysql

I am trying to pull data starting from today, to last 10 transactions i.e. I am getting the first 10 transactions and then I want to apply scroll up / down to move to previous 10 / next 10 transactions.

```
SELECT * FROM table_transaction LIMIT 10
```

I tried the above query this gives a LIMIT of 10 starting from the top (Today's to last 10 transaction details)

How do I implement the above logic?

Can somebody help me fix this?

Comment: why? why do you want to complicate your app? you would need some prev/next buttons and the code to get prev/next rows. why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROWID` column of the sqlite tables. This column is automatically managed by the sqlite.

[Sqlite Documantation](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you want get 10 starting from the top

SELECT * FROM table_transaction LIMIT 0,10

and if you want next 10 item:

```
SELECT * FROM table_transaction LIMIT 1,10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OrderBy Clause for geting last n number of transaction -

```
SELECT * FROM table_transaction LIMIT 10 ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME DESC
```

above query returns last 10 inserted transaction.

For Scrolling you have to create logic create an integer variable say 'last_order_id' and assign it to max order id.

In your query pass last order id and every time you execute query update 'last_order_id'.

So your updated query will be -

```
 SELECT * FROM table_transaction LIMIT 10 ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME DESC INNER JOIN table_transaction.order_id<last_order_id;
```

hope it will help you.